# Format a python list and search for patterns

Tags: python, list, search, pattern-matching

I am getting rows from a spreadsheet with mixtures of numbers, text and dates
I want to find elements within the list, some numbers and some text
for example

```
sg = [500782, u'BMOU9015488', u'SD4', u'CLOSED', -1, '', '', -1]
sg = map(str, sg) 
#sg = map(unicode, sg) #option?
if any("-1" in s for s in sg):
    #do something if matched
```

I don't feel this is the correct way to do this, I am also trying to match stuff like -1.5 and -1.5C and other unexpected characters like OPEN15 compared to 15

I have also looked at

```
sg.index("-1")
```

If positive then its a match (Only good for direct matches)

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't feel this is correct or this is not correct ? What does this code that you don't want, and what is it missing ?

Comment: I get intermittent results and am not sure if I should be using str or unicode in the map

Comment: If you want to match substrings, use strings.

Comment: thanks, I will check failed matches on a case by case basis, hopefully that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a function for each case, I would do it this way:

```
def stub1(elem):
    #do something for match of type '-1'
    return
def stub2(elem):
    #do something for match of type 'SD4'
    return        
def stub3(elem):
    #do something for match of type 'OPEN15'
    return

sg = [500782, u'BMOU9015488', u'SD4', u'CLOSED', -1, '', '', -1]
sg = map(unicode, sg) 
patterns = {u"-1":stub1, u"SD4": stub2, u"OPEN15": stub3} # add more if you want

for elem in sg:
    for k, stub in patterns.iteritems():
        if k in elem:
            stub(elem) 
            break
```

Where stub1, stub2, ... are the fonctions that contains the code for each case.
It will be called (max 1 time per strings) if the string contains a matching substring.

Comment: never use the str function on a unicode object. If it contains non-ascii chars it will crash your prog. Use the unicode function instead, and compare with unicode literals

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "*I don't feel this is the correct way to do this*" ? Are you not getting the result you expect ? Is it too slow ?

Maybe, you can organize your data by columns instead of rows and have a more specific filters. If you are looking for speed, I'd suggest using the numpy module which has a very intersting function called **select()**

[Scipy select example](http://wiki.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#select)

By transforming all your rows in a numpy array, you can test several columns in one pass. This function is amazingly efficient and powerful ! Basically it's used like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = array(...)
conds = [a < 10, a % 3 == 0, a > 25]
actions = [a + 100, a / 3, a * 10]
result = np.select(conds, actions, default = 0)
```

All values in **a** will be transformed as follow:

- A value `100` will be added to any value of **a** which is smaller than `10`
- Any value in **a** which is a multiple of `3`, will be divided by `3`
- Any value above `25` will be multiplied by `10`
- Any other value, not matching the previous conditions, will be set to `0`

Bot **conds** and **actions** are lists, and must have the same number of arguments. The first element in **conds** has its action set as the first element of **actions**.

It could be used to determine the index in a vector for a particular value (eventhough this should be done using the **nonzero()** numpy function).

```
a = array(....)
conds = [a <= target, a > target]
actions = [1, 0]
index = select(conds, actions).sum()
```

This is probably a stupid way of getting an index, but it demonstrates how we can use **select()**... and it works :-)

Comment: Not that slow just unreliable

Comment: What do you mean by "unreliable" ?

Comment: Well the data is unpredictable and I found that I was stripping the fractions from the numbers, that and 1k other "challenges" that are not part of this question. I have used numpy, its an amazing library, thanks for reminding me about it

Comment: Meaning the "conditions" list would be tricky to write... I see :-)